# "This computer has dynamically assigned IP addresses" error when installing Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

This is a working Windows Server 2008 that I should install Active Directory on it.

I found http://www.howtogeek.com/99323/ and followed the steps. After **Additional Domain Controller Options**, I'm asked the question ***"This computer has dynamically assigned IP addresses"***.

[image]

As I see, the message states that **Dynamic IP addressing** has been used for the server, while this is wrong.

When I come to **Network And Sharing Center**, and click on **Local Area Connections** -> **Properties** -> **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** -> **Properties**, I see that the main IP address (as well as DNS Server) and also all other IP addresses are assigned statically. So it should be OK.

I cannot believe any server using dynamic IP(s)!

Note: No IPv6 has been set for the server.

Please tell me why the error is given and which of the options available, should I choose?

Note that it's a production server and is working with many users in WORKGROUP. No change should be affected nor to the IPs, neither to users connecting to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't set a static IPv6 address. If you're not going to use IPv6 then it's safe to ignore that warning and continue.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer. What you mean by `ignoring`? Should I answer __YES__ or __NO__?

Comment: It asks you if you want to continue or not. Select Yes to continue, or select No to abort...

Comment: Thank you. It's a very busy server that should be changed. It is really sensitive I think.